# What is the minimal depth of a 4-ary tree with n nodes?

Tags: data-structures, tree

The question is:

What is the minimal depth of a 4-ary tree with `n` nodes?

I can't find the correct log that is the answer, I know that for `n = 1` the depth is `0`, if `2 <= n <= 5` it is `1`, if `6 <= n <= 21` it is `2`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a math question.

Lets find the relation `f` between the height `h` and the number of nodes `n` in a **full** tree. I'll to it with recursion.

`n = f(h)`. The base is easy, as you said: `f(0)=1`.

We can see that each level contains exactly `4^i` nodes, where `i` is the distance from the root. So, after summarizing all levels we have:

`f(h) = 4^h + f(h-1) = 4^h + 4^(h-1) + ... 4^1 + 4^0 = (4^(h+1)-1)/3 =n [sum of geometric series]`

Isolating `h`:

`h = log_4(3n+1) - 1` and you should take the `ceil()` of that, because you want it to apply on non-full trees as well.

---

Generalization for k-ary is easy now, as:

`f_k(h) = (k^(h+1)-1)/(k-1)`, so `h = ceil(log_k((k-1)n + 1) - 1)`